# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can somebody give mi idea, how to solve this integral?

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, dx$$

Comment: add $\cos(x)-\cos(x)=0$ in the numerator and split the integral in two parts..cool eh?

Comment: complex analysis

Comment: @Euler_Salter not necessary at all

Comment: @tired , right, but I have an exam soon about complex analysis, so that's all I see when I look at integrals lol

Comment: use the $\tan$ half angle substitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writting $\sin x+\cos x = \sqrt{2}\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\right)$, the integral can be written as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin x}{\sin(\pi/4+x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin(\pi/4-u)}{\sin u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{\tan u}\,\mathrm{d}u+\frac{\pi}{8},$$
where we used $\sin(\pi/4-u) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\cos u - \sin u)$ in the last equality.

Comment: how does this help? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Define $I$ = $\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, dx$ and $J$ = $\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, dx$

Now, what about $J$ + $I$ and $J$ - $I$ ?

Can you get it from here?

Comment: Very fine solution!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x}=\frac{1}{2}(\tan 2x - \sec 2x+1)$$

Proof:

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x}=\frac{\sin x(\cos x-\sin x)}{\cos 2x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin 2x+\cos 2x -1}{\cos 2x}=\frac{1}{2}(\tan 2x - \sec 2x+1)$$

Now integrate $\tan 2x$, $\sec 2x$ and $1$.